# How can I put mysql existing columns in new order on phpmyadmin by a practical way?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I know long way to change them but I have so many tables I have to edit. It takes so much time.

**Does anyone know how to put them order by a practical way?**

Comment: what do you mean by 'put them order by a practical way'?What exactly you want to rearrange?please elaborate with sample code.

Comment: So far, I don't know a way in phpmyadmin but sql wise you can.

Comment: The order of columns in a table is irrelevant. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as phpmyadmin there is none but you could do it programmatically via SQL like:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name_Here MODIFY COLUMN column4 int(11) AFTER column2
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name_Here MODIFY COLUMN column4 int(11) FIRST
```

Comment: glad to be of help @Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

As of phpMyAdmin version 4.0.0 you can easily rearrange the column order by dragging and dropping. Click on the `Move columns` link in the table structure page and rearrange the column order in the popup dialog.

[image]